# Orika mapper maps nulls even mapNulls(false) and mapNullsInReverse(false)

Tags: java, orika

I'm using Orika mapper to map JPA entity to DTO and vice versa. The problem is that I don't have entity ID in the DTO object so I want to preserve the JPA entity id. For this reason I'm switched off mapNulls(false) and mapNullsInReverse(false).
My mapper Bean is like this-

```
@Bean
    public MapperFactory roadAssisanceMapperFactory() {
        MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
        mapperFactory.classMap(RoadAssistance.class, RoadAssistanceDto.class)
                .mapNulls(false).mapNullsInReverse(false)
                .exclude("city").exclude("country").exclude("region").exclude("images")
                .byDefault().register();
        return  mapperFactory;
    }
```

I don't have any constructors in both of the entities and I'm using tha mapper with `roadAssisanceMapperFactory().getMapperFacade().map(roadAssistanceDto,roadAssistance);`
When orika maps the entities, I want to have the id filed in the roadAssistance instance preserved, because in the roadAssistanceDto it is null.
Orika version is 1.5.2

Answer (score 1):

I think that your code should work based on my tests and [Orika documentation](https://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/advanced-mappings.html).

One alternative though is globally avoiding mapping nulls. You must declare it when building your MapperFactory. In your case :

```
MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().mapNulls(false).build();
```

Note that since this is the MapperFactory definition, there is no direction. Null values won't be mapped whatever the source or destination classes are and mapNullsInReverse() method does not exists in the MapperFactory Builder.

Comment: once i have a source and a target object, how can i set from the target to the source, like vice versa mapping converter ?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your question. Do you want to not map nulls in both directions ?

Comment: solved using BidirectionalConverter, in case i should map from A to B and the float to double conversion must have a converter, i was trying to use MapAtoB and MapBtoA, but it didn't work...